# SQLite - retrieve set of lat, long from the table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, sqlite

I have stored some Latitude and Longitude in a SQLite Database, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Database name: `database`

Table name: `table`

Fields in table Table:

```
* Name

* Score
```

I am developing an iPhone application. In that, if I give a `latitude`,`longitude` and a `range`(distance) as input, I should get the set of `latitudes` & `longitudes` from the database for the given `range` as the result. For example,

If I give the input parameters as

`Latitude -> 40.7000, Longitude -> -73.9500 and Range -> 30 miles`, it should check the database for the `Latitude & Longitude` in the given `range` and return the `result`. 
So, the `result` should be

```
40.752199, -73.996696
40.793019, -73.969574
40.750898, -73.86898
40.675431, -73.954811
40.68194, -73.927689
```

How could I work this out in iPhone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the Haversine function. This page has a great SQLite function that works well and fast.

http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71

If that one doesn't work for you, search for Haversine and you'll find one that does.

You many need to add a "WHERE distance < 30" to your SQL. You may also need to adjust the numbers used to get miles instead of kilometers.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two different ways to solve you Task.

1. To make quite complicate SQL request, with some mathematic. SELECT  FROM  WHERE (x-center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2 (do no forgive show you radius not in miles but in grad.)
2. read all coordinates from DB with latitude in rande r-30 miles < center_x < r+30 miles. and than reduce all coords which not fix in your requirements... there you can use CoreLocation Framework. "[location1 getDistanceFrom:location2]"